# Как подключить js скрипт перед тегом body для модуля 1c bitrix?

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Я хотел подключить js скрипт для модуля, но консоль выдает ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
или
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at HTMLDocument. (script.js?1692022393412:6:20)
at i (jquery-1.12.4.min.js?168665435097163:2:27449)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.min.js?168665435097163:2:28213)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.min.js?168665435097163:2:30006)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.12.4.min.js?168665435097163:2:30368)
```

Эти ошибка выходят не всегда, но как я понимаю, изображения, по которым ведётся поиск, не успевают прогрузиться, что приводит к ошибкам. Я в файле include подключил скрипт при помощи
Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addJs();
Но этот способ подключает скрипт в head, а мне нужно подключить скрипт в конце body, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможно ваш скрипт стоит запускать только после загрузки DOM дерева

Comment: В настройках главного модуля есть флаг "Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы"

Comment: Я использую $( document ).ready(), не знаю, вроде должно было помочь.

Comment: Так же я боюсь, что перенос всех скриптов в body может навредить работоспособности модуля, мне бы только этот скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать javascript типа модуль. Модули выполняются после того, как загружены все остальные элементы страницы и в том порядке, в каком они указаны на странице. К сожалению, у битрикса нет встроенной поддержки модулей, поэтому придётся немного извратиться.

Идея в следующем: помещаем скрипты модулей в своё пространство строк (тогда битрикс не выводит их автоматически) и выводим их там, где нужно.

Подключаем модуль javascript в шаблоне компонента:

```
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString("<script type='module' src='" . CUtil::GetAdditionalFileURL($templateFolder . '/my_script.js') . "'></script>",
true, 'BOTTOM');
```

CUtil::GetAdditionalFileURL нужен для решения проблем с кэшированием в браузере. "BOTTOM' - это имя нашего пространства строк.

Теперь выводим его где нужно, например, в footer.php:

```
            <?
            echo "<!-->\n";
            echo Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->getStrings('BOTTOM');
            echo "<!-->\n";
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```